# How do I "run" a dockerfile from a github repo I have cloned?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, github, terminal

This may be pretty obvious but I am just not getting it. I have docker install on my machine. I can run

```
docker run hello-world
```

and it works fine. Now though I have a github project I have cloned which has a dockerfile in it called DockerfileLeanFoundation. When i try and run:

```
docker run DockerfileLeanFoundation
```

I get an error saying

```
docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
```

How can i "run" the DockerfileLeanFoundation so that installs all the specified dependencies somewhere I can then use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to `docker run` is a Docker *image*.  What you have cloned from a GitHub is effectively the *source* to a Docker image, that you compile with the `docker build` command to create an image.  That is, if I have a `Dockerfile` that contains:

```
FROM fedora
RUN mkdir -p /var/www; echo "This is a test" > /var/www/index.html
CMD darkhttpd /var/www --port 80
```

I can create an image named `testimage` like this (running this command in the same directory as my `Dockerfile`):

```
docker build -t testimage .
```

And then I can run the image like this (using `-p` to bind the container's port 80 to my host's port 8081):

```
docker run -p 8080:80 testimage
```

And now on my host I can access the web server container we just created:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080
This is a test
```

If I don't want to build my own image, I can pull a prebuilt image from docker hub with the `docker pull` command.  E.g., I know that there exists an image named `mysql`, so I can run:

```
docker pull mysql
```

To make the image available to my local Docker service.

You didn't provide any links to the GitHub repository you're working with, so I can't comment on the specifics, but hopefully this gives you some ideas on how to move forward.  You may also want to spend some time with the excellent documentation at https://docs.docker.com/.